# AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'items' Error when Looping

Tags: python, python-2.7

```
def printdash():
    print('-' * 10)


# creates a mapping of state to abbreviation
states = {
'Oregon': 'OR',
'Florida': 'FL',
'California': 'CA',
'New York': 'NY',
'Michigan': 'MI'
}

# creates a basic set of states with some cities in them

cities = {
'CA': 'Sacramento',
'MI': 'Lansing', 
'FL': 'Tallahasee'}

# add some more cities to the list
cities['NY'] = 'Albany'
cities['OR'] = 'Eugene'

# Print out some cities
printdash()
print('New York State has: ', cities['NY'])
print('Oregon has: ', cities['OR'])

# print some states
printdash()
print 'Michigan\'s abbreviation is: ' , states['Michigan']
print 'Florida\'s abbreviation is: ', states['Florida']

# do it by using the state then cities dict. Nested dicts!
printdash()
print 'Michigan has: ', cities[states['Michigan']]
print 'Florifa has: ', cities[states['Florida']] 

# print every states abbreviation
printdash()
for states, abbrev in states.items():
    print '%s is abbreviated as %s' % (states, abbrev)
# end

# print every city in each state
printdash()
for abbrev, cities in cities.items():
    print '%s has the city %s' % (abbrev, cities)
# end

# doing both at the same time
printdash()
for state, abbrev in states.items():
    print '%s state is abbreviated %s and has city %s' % (state, abbrev,  cities[abbrev])
```

Each time i run it it will get to Line 54 (the last for loop) and then raise the Attribute Error flag. For the life of me i cant figure out what I am doing wrong as the other two loops, set up in mostly the same fashion work without issue.

Looking up other solutions on this site, i found the examples used to be a bit more complex than i could understand and the solutions seemed to be a little more specific than this very general case.

Shanks!

Comment: You override the `states` name if your first loop.

Answer (score 2):

When you assign `states` as the target in your first loop you re-assign the name for `states` to the first item of the `states.items()` tuple.

Here's a simplified version of what you are doing:

```
>>> i = "hello"
>>> for i in range(2): print i
... 
0
1
>>> i
1
```

As you see, `i` is an `int` after the loop and not an `str`, the value it refers to has **changed**.

---

As a solution simply rename the `states` in your loop to something else, like `state` or `tmp_states`. So:

```
for state, abbrev in states.items():
    print '%s is abbreviated as %s' % (state, abbrev)
```

Additionally do the same for the other loops where the same pattern exists, like `for abbrev, cities in cities.items():` -> `for abbrev, city in cities.items()`.

Answer (score 1):

The line

```
for states, abbrev in states.items():
    print('%s is abbreviated as %s' % (states, abbrev))
```

causes the trouble.

As the scope of loop variables in python is not limited to the loop (you can say, they 'leak' into your program), after this line `states` will be a string.

You can debug this by running

```
print(states)
for states, abbrev in states.items():
    print('%s is abbreviated as %s' % (states, abbrev))
print(states)
```

which will print

```
----------
{'California': 'CA', 'Michigan': 'MI', 'New York': 'NY', 'Florida': 'FL', 'Oregon': 'OR'}
California is abbreviated as CA
Michigan is abbreviated as MI
New York is abbreviated as NY
Florida is abbreviated as FL
Oregon is abbreviated as OR
Oregon
```

Additionally, you should check your use of `print`. Please stick with one version of the print statement, either `print 'foo'` **OR** `print('foo')`. The second usage (as function) is the only one that will work in Python 3.X.

Comment: On this front i found the printring of certain strings + variables to have an awkward result if i did printing as a function. Normally i use print as a function, mostly for consistency sake

Answer (score 1):

Both 'cities' and 'states' are being overwritten in the first and second for loops. Using different variable names should fix it.